# Can i create an admin with capabilities to manage group of users in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming

Can i create an admin with capabilities to manage only a group of users in wordpress, like if i have 100 users in my database but i want to create an admin with capabilities to manage only 20 users and another admin to manage only 40 users.
Is this even possible using wordpress, are there any plugins that can help me doing this?

Comment: yes you can just google of what you want workpress is an old CMS and an old community a lot of contributor a lot of extension addons ... etc an example of plugin : https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/groups/

Comment: I know i can create groups for users but how can i make an admin to manage a specific group?

Comment: Isn't simple but you need to create a specific module as custum module hooks some functionality ("overwrite core functions and triggers as an observer") you need to create your own template form, your request ... you can find more about this on the web.